# JAXB + SAX + Open JDK 8 Getting Connection Reset by Client Exception

Tags: java, java-8, xml-parsing, jaxb, saxparser

My code downloads XML report from net and assigns the raw XML to a String variable. It then creates a SAXPaser like so:

```
try {
             SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    
             spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
             spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
             spf.setValidating(true); // Not required for JAXB/XInclude
    
             XMLReader xr = (XMLReader) spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
             xr.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false); //with true report could not be parsed
             xr.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false); // This may not be strictly required as DTDs shouldn't be allowed at all, per previous line.
             xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
             xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
             return new SAXSource(xr,  new InputSource(new StringReader(output)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It then calls jaxb method to unmarshal the XML like so

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(saxSource);
```

This triggers the following exception. Looked up the class in docs and "ClassLoader:null"

factoryClassName - fully qualified factory class name that provides implementation of javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.

classLoader - ClassLoader used to load the factory class. If null current Thread's context classLoader is used to load the factory class.

I saw advice given by others on SOF that said don't use "com.sun" packages. Unfortunately I have to use Java 8, specifically:

openjdk version "1.8.0_392"

The code behind the exception worked with Oracle Java 8 as far as I know. I will appreciate any help.

Thank you

```
JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset]
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:246)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
        at com.matrix.clientmanager.ws.nipr.ScbDownloadReport.downloadReport(ScbDownloadReport.java:74)
        at com.matrix.clientmanager.autobatch.RunLicenseConfig.checkReportResults(RunLicenseConfig.java:325)
        at com.matrix.clientmanager.autobatch.RunLicenseConfig.<init>(RunLicenseConfig.java:87)
        at com.matrix.clientmanager.autobatch.AutoBatch.runLicenseConfig(AutoBatch.java:3352)
        at com.matrix.clientmanager.autobatch.RunAutoBatch.main(RunAutoBatch.java:1111)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:331)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1401)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1305)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1271)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1160)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1044)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:958)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:642)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
        ... 8 more
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81)
                at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:362)
                ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: Could you have more detail about the SSL Exception by activating ssl debug options with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` ? Maybe it's just missing certificate import in your openjdk keystore ? Or TLS version disabled in your openjdk configuration ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens I am unable to edit the post.  Utilities.java:73|the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=nipr.com) was replaced with                                  (type=host_name (0), value=nipr.com) javax.net.ssl|SEVERE|01|main||TransportContext.java:3                                                                                                                                                          23|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Connection reset (

Comment: I think it's my fault cause I reformatted the exception below due to many extra spaces. Just wait for it to be updated and then add the info (beware of confidential data shared)

Answer (score 0):

Someone can probably benefit from this answer.

There was this DTD in the prologue of the XML

```
<!DOCTYPE SCB_Report SYSTEM 'https://example.com/html/SCB_XML_Report.dtd'>
```

The firewall was blocking the URL.